# Why gcc doesn't recognize -rdynamic option?

Tags: c, gcc

I got a gcc compilation error:

```
gcc-4.9: error: unrecognized command line option '-rdynamic'
```

and I tested compilation with -rdynamic in some environments. While I used the same version of gcc (4.9.2), in some environments gcc worked well, but  others (e.g. Homebrew gcc 4.9.2_1, cygwin 64bit) not. What makes the difference?

Comment: It seems that it is option for linking, not compilation. Please post command that causes that error.

Comment: I tried `gcc-4.9 -rdynamic hello_world.c`. Originally, I got this error message from `make` for a makefile generated by autotools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`-rdynamic` passes the flag `-export-dynamic` to ELF linker, **on targets that support it**.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Executable formats in OS X and Windows are not ELF, thus the option `-rdynamic` is not supported building for these operating systems.

Comment: Thanks. Former gccs and clang seem to ignore this option when not available.

Comment: so what is the answer? this is what's written everywhere. but what if i still need my symbols exported?

Comment: @DaveAnkin have a look at dllexport