# Trouble installing therubyracer gem due to compiler issue on mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, therubyracer

I've been trying to install the gem, therubyracer on my mac with OS X El Capitan for a rails app, but I keep getting an error associated with the -rdynamic flag, which results in failure to build the native extensions.

```
Amory:coursequestionbank masonscott$ gem install therubyracer
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/masonscott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160301-14168-1g6b007.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling accessor.cc
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-rdynamic'
make: *** [accessor.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/masonscott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.2/gem_make.out
```

I've tried searching everywhere and it seems like the compiler should ignore the rdynamic flag, but for some reason mine doesn't. I tried updating by gcc to to gcc5, but that still did not resolve the issue. What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems installing therubyracer (because of the problems with libv8). I think you can try with this.

```
$ gem uninstall libv8
$ gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.0'
```

Another way is as follows

```
gem uninstall libv8
brew install v8
gem install therubyracer
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
```

and do bundle install. I think it could solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks I think I figured it out. I had to change the gcc compiler to version 4.2. For some reason the newer gcc versions don't just ignore the -rdynamic flag, which is only present for compiling on linux and is not actually compatible with windows and osx [according to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534519/why-gcc-doesnt-recognize-rdynamic-option)